# AVPlayerViewController delegate function not called when user seek

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

I have been trying to get the notification from `Avplayerviewcontroller` when user seek. I found a method in `AvplayerControllerdelegate` which is called when user scrub however that function is not getting called.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, AVPlayerViewControllerDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let url = URL(string:
        "https://dl.pagal.link/upload_file/367/382/7491/Bollywood%20MP4%20Video%20Songs%202015/Super%20Girl%20From%20China%20-%20Sunny%20Leone%20Mp4/Super%20Girl%20From%20China%20-%20Video%20Song%20-%20Sunny%20Leone%20-%20MP4.mp4")
    let player = AVPlayer(url: url!)
    let playerController = AVPlayerViewController()
    playerController.player = player
    playerController.delegate = self
    self.addChildViewController(playerController)
    self.view.addSubview(playerController.view)
    playerController.view.frame = self.view.frame

    player.play()

}


func playerViewController(_: AVPlayerViewController, timeToSeekAfterUserNavigatedFrom: CMTime, to: CMTime){
    print("Called when scrubb")
}
func playerViewController(_: AVPlayerViewController, willResumePlaybackAfterUserNavigatedFrom: CMTime, to: CMTime){
    print("Called when scrubs")
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

Comment: Is not there any one who can answer this question.

Comment: did you find your answer?

Comment: Hi @HamedGh
No, its still coming as 0 when you seek.

Comment: I have the same issue. Were you able to resolve this? It also appears that when you seek, the view controller reloads thereby seeking to position 0

Answer (score 8):

Because as [apple developer documents said](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avkit/avplayerviewcontrollerdelegate), its just for Apple Tv

> On Apple TV, you can implement methods related to playback navigation,
> interstitial content, and content proposals.

If you create an app for Apple TV and implement `AVPlayerViewControllerDelegate` you can see use this method but for iphone you can't find this method in  `AVPlayerViewControllerDelegate`

Comment: Thank you! Been bashing my head as to why the delegate methods weren't being called and this explains it.